# It is asking me to install module-init-tools?

Tags: upgrade, init, dkms

Every time I give command sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 they are telling me
`dkms : Depends: module-init-tools but it is not installed`

[image]

Comment: So run `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as a screenshot, post it as text.